# How to publish a full self-contained .NetCoreApp as exe?

Tags: c#, publish, self-contained

I'm trying to publish an usable exe-file of my C# .NetCoreApp2.2 console application.

I have written a little application in C# using the Visual Studio Code IDE. I started by typing `dotnet new console` and opened the project within Visual Studio Code. I installed some third-party-libraries like log4net and DocumentFormat.OpenXml.

I can debug my application within Visual Studio Code - no problems. I can run `dotnet run` within the project source directory - no problems. I can also run `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained true` without any problems.

After the publish command I get the expected .exe-file (and a lot of other files?) within the expected subdirectory.

Now to the problem:
As soon as I try to execute the .exe-file I get an unhandled expection.

I do have third-party-libraries referenced, but as I understand it, the self-contained option should take care about that - does it?

I have googled and saw some results describing the publish-process talking about a `project.json` - file which I do not have. Also people describe that this file will be created using the given dotnet-command. For me it never will be created using that command - any additional flag to set?

This is my .csproj-file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nunit3TestAdapter" Version="3.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="*" />
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="1.0.0-beta0006" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Might the "*" for version be a problem?

I would expect to get a single .exe-file (which might be huge) that executes and shows the same output as I will get using the command `dotnet run` within the source-directory of my project.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Very first thing you must do before letting anybody else use your program is to write the code to get a decent error message when your program fails with an unhandled exception.  Not just useful to your users, you need it as well.

Comment: Sounds like your code is causing an exception. Since you're in release mode you don't really have the option of debugging. I would quickly add some printouts in the main function to see where it crashes (maybe envelop the entire main function in a try...catch and print the exception.

Comment: _" describing the publish-process talking about a project.json - file"_ that's outdated, AFAIK. _"I do have third-party-libraries referenced, but as I understand it, the self-contained option should take care about that - does it?"_ - yes. "Selfcontained" will bundle 3rd parties and the .Net Core Runtime with your App.

Comment: Ok I just got confused by folder structure. Looks like it is working as expected. The file I tried to execute is below obj-directory. The file I can execute is below bin-directory - which makes sense... So solved. @Hans Passant that's why I use log4net-library